# Using summation only find A1 and Ratio in a Geometric sequence

Tags: sequences-and-series, geometry

Given: The sum of the first 3 terms of a geometric sequence is 38 and the sum of the first four terms is 65. Find the first term and the common ratio

Comment: I have gotten ar^3 = 27, and articulated the sequence in terms of ar, so, a + ar + ar^3 ... = 38 and ... 65

Comment: @user223171 i believe $a + ar + ar^3 = 38 $ is not correct

Comment: oops a+ ar + ar^2 = 38, my bad

Comment: @user223171 Please check if my solution suits you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have said and according to your notation, 
$$S_3=a+ar+ar^2=38 \,\,\,\,\,\,\text{and} \,\,\,\,\, S_4=a+ar+ar^2+ar^3=65 $$
So $$S_4-S_3=ar^3=65-38=27 \implies ar^3=27=1\cdot3^3$$

Hence $a=\frac{27}{r^3}$

So, we get $$a(1+r+r^2)=38$$ $$\implies \frac{27}{r^3}\cdot(1+r+r^2)=38$$
$$\implies 27(1+r+r^2)=38r^3 $$
$$\implies 38r^3-27r^2-27r-27=0$$

The only real root of this equation is $r=\frac{3}{2}$. The $2$ other roots are complex conjugates.

So the solution is $\boxed{a=8,r=\frac{3}{2}}$.

Comment: I never even thought of doing what you did in the second part, I was sitting like a dumbo with $a=27/r^3$ thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You know $S_3 = 38$ and $S_4 = 65$

Setting $S_n $ as the sum of the first $n $ terms you also know

$$S_n = a_1\frac{1 - r^{n}}{1 - r} $$

Where $S_n = a_1 + a_1r + a_2r^2 + \cdots + a_1r^{n-1} $

All you have to do is solve the equations.

Comment: I am sorry I have been trying to solve it for forever now, can you please hold my hand and take me step by step? Thank you